# Windows Batch File not Validating Year

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have a windows batch script that validates to see if the date format I entered is in the correct format.  Everything is working fine with it except when it gets to the year part of it.  It doesn't seem to validate the year in the correct format of xxxx. It will accept any number.  Where is it breaking, I can't tell?  Fix suggestions?  Thank you!

```
set i=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set dpm[!i!]=%%a
)

set /P "inDate=Please insert FNOL date (MM-DD-YYYY format):  "
if "%inDate:~2,1%%inDate:~5,1%" neq "--" goto invalidDate
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%inDate%") do set "MM=%%a" & set "DD=%%b" & set "YYYY=%%c"
ver > NUL
set /A month=1%MM%-100, day=1%DD%-100, year=1%YYYY%-10000, leap=year%%4
if errorlevel 1 goto invalidDate
if not defined dpm[%month%] goto invalidDate
if %leap% equ 0 set dpm[2]=29
if %day% gtr !dpm[%month%]! goto invalidDate
if %day% lss 1 goto invalidDate

SET fnoldate=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%

ECHO.
SET /P confirmdate=You entered a FNOL date of "%fnoldate%".  Is this correct? [y/n]  
ECHO.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some components of your batch file.

At the top, you should have the following:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Your code has some GoTo references, but it can't go anywhere.  You should add the following at the bottom:

```
GoTo :EOF

:invalidDate
echo Invalid date.
```

Comment: I actually have all that code.  I just took the business end of it out for this example.  It is a rather large batch file.

Comment: When I use the full code, my testing works. What is the exact message you get when you try?

Comment: There actually isn't a message, it works, just not correctly.  You can input mm-dd-y, mm-dd-yy, mm-dd-yyyy, mm-dd-yyyyy, etc. and it puts the whatever number you put into the year in there.  It should ONLY accept yyyy though and nothing more, nothing less.  The mm and dd part of it validate if it is wrong just fine.  The year part isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Giving an example of a failure would have been useful.

Let's take an 'invalid' year like `14`.

Your calculation for 01-01-14 would be year=114-10000

You really need to check that `year` has length 4 first.

```dos
if "%year:~3%=="" goto invaliddate
if not "%year:~4%=="" goto invaliddate
```

- and you are not *then* checking after year-is-numeric for year in a valid range

Comment: I apologize for the lack of example.  I thought I had included it but it must have slipped my mind.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to validate the year:

```
@echo off
set year=1980
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%a in ("%year%") do echo you must enter numeric characters only & goto :EOF
if %year% GEQ 1800 if %year% LEQ 2014 (
    echo year is between 1800 and 2014
  ) else (
   echo enter a year between 1800 and 2014
)
```